# how to make sure both files remain open when comparing two files

Tags: python, file, input, intervals, overlap

I have two fairly big files, each containing a list of intervals with (start, end) information. I have to output the lines in the first file that contain intervals that DO NOT overlap with those in the second file, given that a certain string is in common between the two.

Here is the condition for intervals that do not overlap:

```
(start2 - end1) * (end2 - start1) < 0    TRUE
```

Here is my first test file (tab-delimited). In this file, column [8] is the (start + 1) and the end can be calculated by adding the length indicated in column [5] to the start value.

```
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chrX    131072906   0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr5    24260   0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr8    93179690    0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr1    228757224   0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr1    228759444   0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr1    228752768   0   36M 36
TagX    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr1    14355   0   36M 36
TagX    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr1    24260   0   36M 36
TagX    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr1    26320   0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr1    228766167   0   36M 36
```

The second test file (tab-delimited) indicating the starts and ends of the undesirable intervals:

```
chr1    14361   14408
chr1    16713   16749
chr1    18907   19048
chr1    19972   20405
chr1    20531   20679
chr1    21949   22075
chr1    23804   24038
chr1    24088   24250
chr1    24255   24448
chr1    26356   26412
```

The output should look something like this (TagX's overlap with the intervals in the second file and therefore should disappear, but only if columns [7] in file1 and [0] in file2 contain the same string):

```
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chrX    131072906   0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr5    24260   0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr8    93179690    0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr1    228757224   0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr1    228759444   0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr1    228752768   0   36M 36
TagO    XXXX    xxxx    46  a   36  +   chr1    228766167   0   36M 36
```

And here is my code...

```
import sys

A = sys.argv[1]
B = sys.argv[2]

soap = open(A, 'r')
bed = open(B, 'r')

with soap as input1:
    for row1 in input1:
        chrom1 = row1.strip().split()[7]
        start1 = int(row1.strip().split()[8]) - 1
        end1 = start1 + int(row1.strip().split()[5])

        with bed as input2:
            for row2 in input2:
                chrom2 = row2.strip().split()[0]

                if chrom1 == chrom2:
                    start2 = int(row2.strip().split()[1])
                    end2 = int(row2.strip().split()[2])
                    test = (start2 - end1)*(end2 - start1)

                    if test < 0:
                        print row1.strip()
```

Then I run it using the following command in Terminal (Mac OS X):

```
python remove.py file1.txt file2.txt > test_out.txt
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "remove.py", line 16, in <module>
    with bed as input2:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with` block for "bed" is closing the file after the block is complete.  But while normally you would embed the `open` function call inside your `with` statement like so:

```
with open(B, 'r') as input2
```

instead you are opening the file only once and then trying to operate on it with `with` multiple times, inside your `for` loop.  So python is complaining that the file object has only been opened once, but you're trying to work with it repeatedly.

If you want to start at the beginning of `input2` every time through your for loop, then you can embed your `open` function call in the `with` statement as above.

You could also decline to use the "with" syntax at all (opening and closing the file manually), or you could move the second "with" to encompass your for loop instead of having it inside, and then use `seek()` to return to the beginning inside the loop.

It may be more efficient, if the file is small, to read the contents into memory (a list, for instance) before entering the for loop at all, and iterating over the list only.

Comment: Thanks!! Now I'm getting mostly `TagX` lines as the output, which is the opposite of what I want, but at least the code is running!! Almost there!!! :D